# How can I calculate the quantile regression in R

Tags: r, statistics

I was asked to help with the named topic. I do not understand how to proceed in that case, though.

Given is a data set on the DAX revenues for the last 30 years (per month) and to calculate is the quantile regression based on a constant value?

I was given the following code but do not know where the issue might be.

```
citation()
rm(list=ls())
setwd(dirname(rstudioapi::getActiveDocumentContext()$path))
```

## Einlesen der Daten

```
library(readr)
data_DAX <- read_delim("DAX-Performenceindex Kopie 2.csv", 
    delim = ";", escape_double = FALSE, col_types = cols(Monat = col_date(format = "%Y-%m"), 
        Kurs = col_double(), ...3 = col_skip()), 
    na = "null", comment = "#", trim_ws = TRUE)
```

## Erster Überblick

```
str(data_DAX)
summary(data_DAX$Kurs)
plot(data_DAX$Monat, data_DAX$Kurs, xlab="Jahr", ylab="Kurs", main="Streudiagramm für den DAX") # Streudiagramm
#plot(ecdf(data_DAX$Kurs), do.points=FALSE) # empirische Verteilungsfunktion
```

## Wachstumsrate: stetige Rendite

```
options(scipen=999)
Rendite <- diff(log(data_DAX$Kurs))
data_DAX$Rendite <- NA
data_DAX$Rendite[-1] <- Rendite
#cat("stetige Monatsrenditen:", round(data_DAX$Rendite[2:8], 4), sep = " ")
hist(Rendite)
boxplot(Rendite)
mean(Rendite)
sd(Rendite)
plot(ecdf(Rendite), do.points=FALSE)
```

## QQ-Plot

```
help (qqplot)
qqnorm(data_DAX$Rendite[-1], main="QQ-Plot zwischen DAX Quantile & Quantile einer Normalverteilung", xlab="DAX Quantile", ylab="Theoretische Quantile", datax=TRUE)
#qqline(data_DAX$Rendite[-1], datax = TRUE, distribution = qnorm, probs = c(0.25, 0.75), qtype = 7)
```

```
help("rq")
library(quantreg)
quantreg0.5 <- rq(Rendite ~ 1 , tau=0.5, data=data_DAX)
summary <- summary(quantreg0.5, se="nid")
#plot(summary(rq(Rendite ~ 1 , tau=0.5)))

#install.packages("ggplot2")
library(ggplot2)
ggplo


#conf <- predict(quantreg0.5, interval="confidence", level=0.95)
#conf_df <- data.frame(x=data_DAX$Monat, ymin=conf[,"lwr"], ymax=conf[,"upr"])



#ggplot(data=data_DAX, aes(x=Monat, y=Rendite)) + geom_point() + stat_quantile(quantiles=0.5) + stat_quantile(quantiles=0.025, alpha=0.25) + stat_quantile(quantiles=0.975, alpha=0.25) +labs(x="Datum", y="Rendite") + theme_bw()
```

```
#install.packages("quantreg")
library(quantreg)
K <- rep(1, length(Rendite))
quantreg0.5 <- rq(Rendite ~ 1 , tau =0.5) 
summary(quantreg0.5, se="nid")
#signifikanz abchecken
```

```
n <- length(dax1$Rendite)
plot(x = 1:n, y = dax1$Rendite, ylim = c(min(dax1$Rendite), max(dax1$Rendite)), xlab = "xx", ylab = "Rendite")
abline(h = quantreg0.5$coef, col = 2, lty = 2)
#points(x = 1:n, y = quantreg0.5$fitted, col = 4)

plot(summary(rq(dax1$Rendite ~ dax1$Kurs,tau = 1:49/50,data=dax1))) #KEINE KONSTANTE
#anova.rq #TEST NOCH MACHEN
help("rq")
length(quantreg0.5$fitted)
```

#graph

```
quantreg <- rq(data_DAX$Rendite[-1] ~ 1, tau=seq(0.05, 0.99, by=0.05), data_DAX)
summary(quantreg)
#quantreg.plot <- summary(quantreg)
#plot(quantreg.plot)
```

## Einzelne Abschnitte

```
dax1 <- subset(data_DAX, data_DAX$Monat >= "2008-01-01" & data_DAX$Monat <= "2012-12-01")
```

```
hist(dax1$Rendite)
boxplot(dax1$Rendite)
plot(dax1$Monat, dax1$Rendite)
```

```
library(quantreg)
quantreg0.5 <- rq(Rendite ~ 1, tau=0.5, data=dax1)
summary(quantreg0.5)
```

Comment: Thanks for showing the code. What makes you say there is a problem? What problem are you experiencing? Is there an error message, a warning, does R crash, does your computer crash, or do you get results that don't seem correct? If you run the code one line at a time, where is your first indication of a problem?

Comment: We don't have access to your data, so can't run your code. Can you explain exactly what the problem is? All you have told is is that you are supposed to help with a quantile regression. Does the code not work? If so, what is the error you are getting?

Comment: The only obvious problem I see is the line `ggplo` is incomplete. I would recommend deleting it.

Comment: @GregorThomas Hi, thanks for your response! My colleague told me that she gets an error telling her the data has not the same length. 

What irritates me is the fact that the quantile regression has to be calculated by a constant value? I do not get why one would set all values to 1 for X and only regard the Y values for the calculation and why that is necessary

Comment: @AllanCameron can I upload the csv data and the r code somewhere and share the link? Any reommendations, I only know JSfiddle but that won't work :)

Comment: You've shared well over 100 lines of code. What you should do is run the code one line (or one chunk of lines) at a time and figure out **where is the error.** Then you should edit your question and delete most of the code before the error, and most of the code after the error. Share a small subset of the data / other objects in the state they are in before the error - because you will only share a small subset you can put it directly in the question. `dput()` is a great way to share R objects, `dput(your_data[1:5, ])` will make a copy/pasteable version of the first 5 rows of `your_data`.

Comment: You should also tell us what the error says so that we can see it without running your code. (And which line it occurs on.) Please edit your question to make this clear so people don't additionally have to read through all these comments to find the relevant info.

Comment: And quantile regression can use additional predictors. `rq(Rendite ~ 1 , tau =0.5) ` runs an intercept-only model. But you you had a variable named `foo` you could add that to your model with `rq(Rendite ~ 1 + foo, tau =0.5)`. If you go to the `rq` function help page by entering `?rq` and scroll to the bottom  you can see (and run) examples. The `quantreg` package also comes with a [nice introductory vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/quantreg/vignettes/rq.pdf) that would be good to read.